# Templates. adding , getting element char*

Tags: c++, templates, char, containers

I've got a problem with my template class and using it for char*.
I storage elements in class and try to add or get element ,but segmentation fault appear.
Is it possible without class specialisation for type char* ?

Edit 1:
Let's assume that I can't change the code in main function but the class and methods, but without specialisations. Is it possible to handle char* ? ;)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class test
{
public:
    void addItem(T element){
        elements.push_back(element);
    }

    T getItem(int i){
        return elements[i];
    }

    vector<T> elements;
};

int main()
{
    char * cpt[]={"tab","tab2","tab3"};
    test<char*> test1;
    test1.addItem(cpt[1]);
    char * item=test1.getItem(0);
    //Segmentation fault
    // could it be done without specialisation class for char*    ?
    item[0]='Z';
    cout<<item<<endl;
    for(auto v:test1.elements) cout<<v<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[My code](http://ideone.com/p7J2b1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to modify a constant string literal. That gives undefined behaviour; typically a segmentation fault, if the literal is stored in write-protected memory.

In modern C++, the program shouldn't even compile, since the deprecated conversion from a string literal to a non-const `char*` was finally forbidden in C++11.

If you want to store modifiable strings, you're probably best off with `std::string`.

Comment: I can't change the input, so the only reasonable option is doing specialisation right ?

Comment: @whiteNinja: I've no idea what you mean by that. Just use `test<std::string>` instead of `test<char*>`.

Comment: The problem is I can't change that. Only class and methods

Comment: @whiteNinja Please, edit your question and add these information : what do you want to achieve and what you can/can't change in the code you posted. Otherwise we are just guessing.